# When phone is blocked and with screen black... GPS is still working?

Tags: android, gps

im doing an application that will use GPS in background mode, then i need that it works also when my phone is blocked and with black screen.

but i can't find any information about if gps is off when phone is blocked

can someone tell me please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that GPS will also work if you phone is locked and the display is off. There are some GPS apps out there which track your location while you're driving or walking around also when you phone is locked. "My Tracks" (name of an Android app) for example is one of those apps.

But I think you'll have to implement a service so you can handle GPS events in "background mode".

Comment: can someone confirm it plz? my application desing depends on this thing, if it can be done with a normal service, then i can do it, if not, i have to change all my application desing

Comment: CAN SOMEONE CONFIRM IF YES OR NOT PLEASE?

Comment: Why don't you write a small app to test if it'll work locked and with screen turned off? Then you can be sure that it'll work.

Comment: sure i will try it, if no one can tell me this before